# Video Editor Timeline View android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-custom-view

I am trying to create this type of view[image]

You can notice that the video timeline moves to act like the video seek bar and also you can scroll horizontally and vertically, This is what I have created

[image]

I have used ExoPlayer to play and Controller the video Created a Custom view for the frames inside the timeline and implemented the custom view inside a Recyclerview

The view now can scroll horizontally and vertically but I can't make the recyclerview act as a seek bar for the video at all and I don't know what to do

This is my LayoutManager for the Recyclerview

```
val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false)
```

This is the custom view Layout the I inflate inside the adapter

```
<HorizontalScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <com.example.example.customViews.ui.CustomSeekBar2
        android:id="@+id/customVideoSeekBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I thought about something like using `while(videoIsPlaying) recyclerview.scrollTo()` but I can't do this since the horizontal scroll comes from the inflated layout, not the recyclerview itself